# Start menu Search not showing anything, even after clean window install

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I've tried every fix online, from a simple restart, End Cortana, Restart Explorer, check windows search in Services.msc, even install a new clean copy of Windows 10 (1903; 18362.356), and yet nothing is working

[image]

Comment: Update: Turn out, Microsoft was to blame, they said it was Bing server error: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/windows-message-center#387